# Select Distinct Records and count other columns related to record

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to create a SQL Query wherein it will pick all distinct records from the first column and do a count of all the items related to that column similar to a countifs command in Excel. I am new to SQL and I am really lost at this point. please help.

Sample Table:

| Employee | Item | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EmpA | Red Item | Light |
| EmpB | Red Item | Heavy |
| EmpC | Red Item | Heavy |
| EmpA | Blue Item | Light |
| EmpB | Red Item | Light |
| EmpD | Blue Item | Light |
| EmpA | Red Item | Heavy |
| EmpC | Blue Item | Heavy |
| EmpA | Red Item | Light |
| EmpB | Red Item | Heavy |
| EmpD | Red Item | Light |
| EmpA | Blue Item | Light |
| EmpB | Red Item | Heavy |
| EmpC | Blue Item | Light |
| EmpA | Red Item | Light |
| EmpB | Red Item | Light |
| EmpD | Red Item | Light |

Expected output:

| Employee | RecordCount | Red Item | Blue Item | Light | Heavy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EmpA | 6 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| EmpB | 5 | 5 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| EmpC | 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| EmpD | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

Comment: For a limited number of columns you can use something like `sum(case when Item = 'Red Item' then 1 else 0 end) as RedItem`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use conditional aggregation, which looks something like this:

```
select employee, count(*) as num_items,
       sum(item like 'Red%'),
       sum(item like 'Blue%'),
       sum(weight = 'Light'),
       sum(weight = 'Heavy')
from t
group by employee
```